# php curl extension problem, ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, lighttpd, curl

i've installed (as root)

```
aptitude install curl php5-curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev
```

and added extension=curl.so to my php.ini (i assumed this wasn't done automatically because i'm using Lighty and not apache)

```
service lighttpd restart
```

But still no luck, there is nothing about cURL when I run phpinfo()

curl.so is located in /usr/lib/php5/20090626

Comment: Does the php.ini you added it to match the one in the output of phpinfo() ?

Comment: yep. /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart lighttpd by

sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart

Comment: Nope, it still isn't loading curl.